Why a metric on a set can not be $\infty$?
I ask this question because I came acorss a problem (b) in exercise 3 in page 93 in section 13 in chapter 2 in the second edition of Elementary Analysis by Ross. The question is described below:

Let $B$ be the set of all bounded sequences $\boldsymbol{x} = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots)$. Does $d^{*} (\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} |x_{j} - y_{j}|$ define a metric for $B$?

My answer is yes since it clearly satisfies the first two properties for a metric on a set and $|x_{j} - z_{j}| \le |x_{j} - y_{j}| + |y_{j} - z_{j}|$ hence $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}|x_{j} - z_{j}| \le \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}|x_{j} - y_{j}| + \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}|y_{j} - z_{j}|$ hence $d^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{z}) \le d^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) + d^{*}(\boldsymbol{y}, \boldsymbol{z})$.
But I check the anwser, it says no! Because $d^{*}(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y})$ might be $\infty$ if $\boldsymbol{x} = (1, 1, 1, \cdots)$ and $\boldsymbol{y} = (0, 0, 0, \cdots)$.
But why the metric cannot be $\infty$? I check the definition in the book mentioned above and it does not mention anything about it. I search the questions related to it but nothing can be found.
Any help will be appreciated!

Perhaps the link provided in the close box will help you. Nonetheless it is not at all clear what you are asking. By definition, a metric on a set $X$ is a certain kind of function $d : X \times X \to [0,\infty)$, and so $d(x,y)$ is a real number, not infinity. The example you gave with $x=(1,1,1,...)$ and $y=(0,0,0,...)$ clearly violates that definition and so $d^*$ is not a metric. If you are wondering why the definition of a metric is formulated to disallow $\infty$, the link in the close box should help. But if that's not what you are asking, perhaps you can edit your post to clarify.

Please check the definition in your book again. It certainly says that a metric is a map from $X \times X$ to the non-negative reals.

So sorry that I asked a so so stupid question and did not check the definition carefully. orz
